# Modify SP Start Page in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

In O365, if I click the grid navigation and select SharePoint, I go to a start page of mydomain/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx rather than the home page of your main SharePoint site. **I am looking for a way to either, add a more obvious link to our main SP site, or have it redirect to our main site instead of the start page.** This page doesn't seem to be based on a master page I have access to (our usual way of customization). With SP Online, I don't seem to have access to the _layouts folder.

We have added a link to our main SharePoint site in the "promoted sites." The new SP start page MS is rolling out, buries promoted links in the left column as a basic looking link. It's very easy to miss.

A possible workaround is to hide the SharePoint tile, add a custom tile with the same name, and link it to our main SP site. This looks to be my best option right now. Any other suggestions?

Comment: We are going for the workaround of hiding the SharePoint tile and making our own custom tile to replace it. Currently the swap can't be applied globally, but the feature is "In development" here: http://fasttrack.microsoft.com/roadmap?filters=. Until then, the tiles can be swapped per user as-needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a custom tile to the app launcher

To do so follow these steps:

- Select Admin in app launcher (left top corner)
- Settings - Organization profile - add custom tiles for your organization
- Add a custom tile
- Enter Tile name, URL and Image URL and hit "Save"

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. We did this a while back, but there's no way to globally add the custom tile to our Users' launcher. Users can pin the tile to their launcher individually.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change this, however you can change where the root url points to by using the script found on [my GitHub](https://github.com/tb0111/SharepointTools) and then adding a JS redirect onto the new default page shown below.

```
window.location.replace("http://stackexchange.com/");
```